# How to get current date in ASP.NET and telerik:RadTextBox

Tags: asp.net, datetime, telerik, radtextbox

How can I see the **current date** in a **.aspx** file using **telerik RadTextBox**.

I tried this:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" Width="50%" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") %>' />
```

But I can't see anything.

Any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that on the server:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RadTextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
}
```

Comment: I should add "Page_Load" where I have server or in Text?

Comment: Page_Load is a standard server event for any webform. So, yes - in the server code.